# groupby lambda and filling empty rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
status  name    date        count  pass_count
pass    john    2003-04-22  4       2
fail    cici    2003-04-22  4       1
pass    john    2004-04-22  4       2
pass    john    2004-04-22  4       2
fail    lily    2006-05-23  3       0
        lily    2006-05-23  3       0
pass    cici    2008-05-23  3       1
        cici    2008-05-23  3       0
```

I have a data frame and I am trying to return column pass_count.

first groupby name, secondly, check status and count how many are pass given a name.

my code:

```
df['pass_count'] = df.groupby(['name'])['status'].apply(lambda x: x == 'Pass')
```

The code is not working, and I try to fill the empty 'status' row using `fillna('NaN')` or `fillna('0')`, but the empty 'status' rows still exist?

Any one knows how to fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your dataframe does not have the `pass_count` column yet (if it has, just drop it with `df.drop('pass_count', axis=1)`.

Now let's calculate the number of passes and put that into a dataframe:

```
npass = df.groupby('name')['status'].apply(lambda x: len(x[x == 'pass']))
npass = npass.to_frame(name='pass_count').reset_index()
```

We now have the following dataframe with the right counts associated to each name:

```
In [127]: npass
Out[127]: 
   name  pass_count
0  cici           1
1  john           3
2  lily           0
```

All that's left to do is to merge the two dataframes:

```
In [128]: pd.merge(df, npass)
Out[128]: 
  status  name        date  count  pass_count
0   pass  john  2003-04-22      4           3
1   pass  john  2004-04-22      4           3
2   pass  john  2004-04-22      4           3
3   fail  cici  2003-04-22      4           1
4   pass  cici  2008-05-23      3           1
5    NaN  cici  2008-05-23      3           1
6   fail  lily  2006-05-23      3           0
7    NaN  lily  2006-05-23      3           0
```

and you have the `pass_count` column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing `transform()`, which returns DataFrame having the same length as the original object.

```
df['pass_count'] = df.groupby('name')['status'].transform(lambda x: len(x[x == 'pass']))
```

To fill the empty status column,  it might be the that your data contains white spaces, so you can use:

```
df['status'].replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Which yields:

```
  status  name        date  count  pass_count
0   pass  john  22/04/2003      4           3
1   fail  cici  22/04/2003      4           1
2   pass  john  22/04/2004      4           3
3   pass  john  22/04/2004      4           3
4   fail  lily  23/05/2006      3           0
5    NaN  lily  23/05/2006      3           0
6   pass  cici  23/05/2008      3           1
7    NaN  cici  23/05/2008      3           1
```